# How to print a PDF with titlepage in two-up mode with the title page on the right side?

Tags: windows-7, pdf, printing, adobe-acrobat

This is a followup to [How to make the first page of a PDF display by itself and the succeeding pages display two-up](https://superuser.com/q/235887/91826) - how do I get Acrobat X on Windows 7 to print a file with a title page correctly in two-up mode so that the title page starts on the *right half* of the paper? The pdf in question is the [LuaTeX manual](http://www.luatex.org/svn/trunk/manual/luatexref-t.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepend an empty page in front of the manual. (You may use `gs` and `pdftk` to achieve that.)

I think that's the only way, as you cannot get what you ask for *directly from Acrobat X on Windows 7*.

---

**Create empty page with Ghostscript:**

```
gs -o emptypage.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -r72 -g595x842 -c "showpage"
```

**Prepend emptypage.pdf to your manual:**

```
pdftk emptypage.pdf manual.pdf cat output emptypage+manual.pdf
```