# Adobe-reader double-page layout like a book

Tags: adobe-reader, layout

When setting the Adobe-reader to two-page layout it looks like this:

```
Title, page 1 
page 2, page 3
...
```

But I'd like to view it as if it were printed in a book:

```
empty, Title
page 1, page 2
page 3, page 4
...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make the first page of a PDF display by itself and the succeeding pages display two-up?](http://superuser.com/questions/235887/how-to-make-the-first-page-of-a-pdf-display-by-itself-and-the-succeeding-pages-d)

Answer (score 7):

This may happen because of the cover artwork.
This is how you can fix it in Adobe Reader:

View >> Page Display >> Show Cover Page During Two-up.

The pages will display the way you want.